# Schedule Tasks - Specific action on specific trigger

Tags: windows, task, schedule

I want to start different actions depending on specific triggers. 
For example, for trigger #1, action #1 should be started, for trigger #2, action #2 should be started.

Is this possible using Windows Schedule Task?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, opening a command window and asking information on the `schtasks` command. The explanation will give you a list of triggers you can use, like the following:

```
/SC   schedule     Specifies the schedule frequency.
                   Valid schedule types: MINUTE, HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY,
                   MONTHLY, ONCE, ONSTART, ONLOGON, ONIDLE, ONEVENT.
```

I believe `ONEVENT` is what you're looking for. The documentation and examples of `schtasks /?` are quite helpful.